# Create a IM program (like MSN or Gtalk ) using C++

Tags: c++

My question is that create a IM software like MSN or Gtalk, to have the basic function using C++.

You can use any technology and libary to do that.

Can someone give me a suggestion?

> I add that this not my homework. This
>   is my job question.
>
> Because I am a fresh man in my
>   company.
>
> So, they give me some questions to let
>   me dirty my hand.

Comment: Is this homework?  It looks like it, I would suggest using the "homework" tag.

Comment: @Chris If it is it's a fairly involved project considering the usual homework questions we get. So if it is, kudos on going above and beyond when it comes to cheating in CS classes

Comment: @Meteor A specific question would be helpful, this is just a general goal. Are you looking for C++ libraries to connect to IM networks?

Comment: Qt is good for this kind of project, especially if you need to make a GUI.

Comment: @Michael If people put all the effort into actually doing the assignments that they put into cheating, we wouldn't have software crashes...but you are correct, this one is definitely a doozie

Comment: @Chris Thompson

This is not my homework.

This is my job...

Comment: @Justin Ardini 
Thank you. I will refer to Qt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion from experience with doing this sort of thing before is to find a library that implements Jabber also known as XMPP (Google Talk) for you.  That way all you have to do is create the user interface.  If you are working with Windows, [MSDN](http://www.msdn.com) has some great tutorials for creating user interfaces in C++.   If you are using Linux, you will probably want to look for an X windows tutorial.  Other than that, check out [this link](http://xmpp.org/software/libraries.shtml#cplusplus) for a list of C++ libraries for Jabber/XMPP.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much.

I will go to read XMPP and MSDN.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you will probably want to use a library that already knows how to interface with existing IM clients. Google Talk, for example, uses the XMPP (also known as Jabber) protocol. The XMPP website has links to a number of free C++ libraries to communicate with other XMPP clients (like Google Talk):

http://xmpp.org/software/libraries.shtml

Here is one example of a GPL XMPP library for C++: http://camaya.net/gloox/

Comment: Thank you. I will go to have a look.